# Convert value to Date formate using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've this code below:

```
var ValorData = document.getElementById("RetiraValorDate").innerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

[image]

Without the innerHTML and Replace the result is this:

[image]

How can I convert the result to a date format?

Comment: Please search before asking. This question has been asked many, many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first reverse the date and then ,use Date object to retrieve js date

```js
let str="18/02/2019";

function reverseString(str) {
  
    var splitString = str.split("/");
 
  
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse(); 
 
 
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join("/"); 
   
    return joinArray; 
}

console.log(reverseString(str))

let date =new Date(reverseString(str));
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const dateParts = '18/09/2019'.split('/');
const newDate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0]);

console.log(newDate.toDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the data (in your case "18/02/2019") with slash and pass in correct format that is ISO

var dtArr = ValorData.split("/");
var requriedDate = new Date(dtArr[2]+"-"+dtArr[1]+"-"+dtArr[0]);

in above example requriedDate will contain your date object and you can compare with any other date object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a date, split the string on the slashes, convert each part to a number, then feed the parts in the `Date` constructor. Do not forget to substract 1 from the month since month are 0-based in JavaScript dates:

```js
const dateParts = document.getElementById("RetiraValorDate")
  .innerHTML
  .replace(/\s/g,'')
  .split('/')
  .map(Number);
  
console.log(new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0]));
```

```html
<span id="RetiraValorDate">
    18/02/2019
    </span>
```